# How do I override this file in theme?

Tags: magento-2.1, module, theme

There is a phtml file from a module that I want to override in my theme.  The path to the file is: `\vendor\mageplaza\magento-2-social-login\view\frontend\templates\form\social.phtml`.

I am trying to figure out what the path should be to my override social.phtml file but I am finding it confusing.  What is the correct path I should put my file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override social.phtml by below path

```
app/design/frontend/YourTheme/Vendor/Mageplaza_SocialLogin/templates/form/social.phtml
```

Example :

As per Magento-2 if you want to override vendor module templates then you need to follow an example

Vendor Module : **mageplaza\magento-2-social-login**

You need to make this directory in your theme like below

**app/design/frontend/YourTheme/Vendor/** : `Mageplaza_SocialLogin`

and module view templates `\view\frontend\templates\form\social.phtml` is under in theme templates folder like : `templates/form/social.phtml`

Finally your template path is :

```
app/design/frontend/YourTheme/Vendor/Mageplaza_SocialLogin/templates/form/social.phtml
```

Comment: How would I have worked that out?  The path and names are structured differently, what is the rule you followed to get the correct path?

Comment: You need to follow magento-2 theme rules.

Comment: That is not a helpful answer.  Your path does not seem to match, you captitalized some letters and removed hypen.  I cannot find any documentaion saying to do that

Comment: Check my updated answer with example.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the same format what we use to override core Magento files into our theme.

Under your theme folder, Create a directory with name Package_Module. So, in your case, Please create a directory named **Mageplaza_SocialLogin**

Put the files following the same path what the base module have and paste the template files under the template directory. It will look like following:

```
app/design/frontend/YourTheme/Vendor/Mageplaza_SocialLogin/templates/form/social.phtml
```

Please refresh cache to get the changes.

Comment: where do you get the module name?  The path says "mageplaza\magento-2-social-login" not "Mageplaza_SocialLogin".  Did you get that from somewhere else?

Comment: mageplaza is your Package name, magento-2-social-login in your module name.
while overriding the files to our theme, you have to follow this standard, use camel case format.
So it will change to Mageplaza_SocialLogin.

I took reference from github.
https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-social-login/blob/master/registration.php